# Searching getstream.io to filter results

Tags: getstream-io

I'm looking to integrate search functionality into my app. If we do a search locally and get a bunch of objectIDs that match the criteria, is there a way to ask Stream "for this specific feed, does this objectID appear in it?", so that we can filter our results based on what a particular user will actually have access to?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported on standard plans.

Per the docs, it is only possible to [retrieve a feed](https://getstream.io/docs/#retrieve) with an ID range (using the `id_lt[e]` or `id_gt[e]` parameters), or at an `offset` from the start of the feed.